# Check bootstrap form is dirty or not

Tags: jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a bootstrap demo page with two tabs, each tab containing a form with a few input fields and a Cancel and Submit button. I want to check the form is dirty or not when I switch the tabs (if any fields have been changed in the form and not submitted yet). If the form is dirty, I want the tab holding that form to be highlighted. I am pretty new to Bootstrap and trying to get this use case working.

I tried Googling a bit around this issue and I found solutions using Angular JS for checking if a form is dirty with bootstrap. Since I have not worked on mv* frameworks like Angular or have any exposure to that area, I would like to have a simple solution using JavaScript or jQuery.

Comment: What on earth is a 'dirty' `<form>`?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: A dirty form is a term used to mean there is data in the fields.

Comment: Are you using JQuery.. I have used this plug in and like it. http://formvalidation.io/

Comment: @w3bMak3r: "*I would like to have a simple solution using JavaScript or jQuery.*" - what do you think? Also, as to the 'dirty' form definition, really?

Comment: check out the plugin above.  it is good cause it supports bootstrap

Comment: Man, these comments are a great example of why people think SO is hostile. Yeesh.

Comment: A form is "dirty" if any of the form fields have changed since the page was loaded. You do not want a user to navigate away from a dirty form without reminding them to submit their changes. It's borrowed from other CS terms including "dirty cache" and "dirty bit" (both defined on Wikipedia).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how you could do this. It's not using Bootstrap, but you can get the idea.

http://jsfiddle.net/98dk8d68/1/

here is a quick mod for the bootstrap version:

http://jsfiddle.net/5pfune55/2/

```js
var dirty = false;

$(':input').on('change keyup', function(){
   dirty = true; 
});

$("#dirtytabs").autotabs({
    show: function (tab) {
        dirty = false;
    },
    hide: function (tab) {
        if (dirty) {
            alert(tab + ' is dirty');
        }
    }
});
```

```css
input, textarea{
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

div.autotab{
    background: #fefefe;
    padding: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.1)
}
```

```html
<div>
    <ul id="dirtytabs" class="autotab">
        <li class="active"><a data-tab="#tab1">tab1</a>

        </li>
        <li><a data-tab="#tab2">tab2</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
    <div style="margin-top:10px" class="autotab">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab">
            <form>
                <input />
                <textarea></textarea>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="tab2" class="tab">
            <form>
                <input />
                <textarea></textarea>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: By saying the form being "dirty", I meant that some input field or record in the form has been changed, but the changes were not submitted. Apologies if my question didn't have enough info,I will try to give more details hereafter , my first day on StackOverflow.

Comment: and how is that any different than what this code is doing?

Comment: Your code works perfectly, I can surely use it :). I was just clarifying what I meant by "dirty" to one of the previous comments.